# How to make reading this instance primitive thread-safe without locking?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, thread-safety

The problem with the below class is when reading `myThreadSafe.Value` it may not return the most up-to-date value.

```
public class ThreadSafe
{   
    private int value;
    public int Value { get { return value; } }

    public void Update()
    {
        Interlocked.Add(ref value, 47); // UPDATE: use interlocked to not distract from the question being asked.
    }
}
```

I realise I could lock when reading it and writing it:

```
public int Value { get { lock(locker) return value; } }

public void Update()
{
    lock(locker)
    {
        value += 47;        
    }
}
```

And I have followed this pattern of using locks always. However I am trying to reduce the number of locks in my code (there are many and they are called frequently, I have profiled and `Montior.Enter()` is taking up more time then I would like - because it is called so many times).

**UPDATE**: I wonder now if that indeed the lock will make any difference in ensuring I am reading the most up to date value, it could still be from one of the machine's CPU caches couldn't it? (All the lock guarantees is mutual exclusive thread access).

I thought `volatile` would be the answer, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(VOLATILE_CSHARPKEYWORD);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true) does say: "This ensures that the most up-to-date value is present in the field at all times", however I read [elsewhere](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) write then read CPU instructions can still be swapped when using `volatile` in which case I could get a previous value for `myThreadSafe.Value` perhaps I could live with that - only being out by one update.

What is the most efficient way I will always get the most up-to-date value for `myThreadSafe.Value`?

**UPDATE:** This code will be compiled and run on CPU Architectures:

- x86
- AMD64 (though I can build as x86)
- PowerPC
- ARM (Little-endian only)

Using the runtimes:

- CLR v4.0
- Mono (I am not sure of the mono runtime versions but if they correspond to the Mono versions: 3.0 at least).

I am hoping to use the same code for all builds!

Comment: How often are you writing to the value vs. reading?

Comment: Will methods from [Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx) work for you?

Comment: I think you need to have a look at the [`ReaderWriterLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) class. It appears to me you have multiple readers but a single writer.

Comment: I could be writing, i.e. calling Update(), from any thread in the ThreadPool up to about 100 times a second. I will be reading from one thread 60 times a second.

Comment: @HansPassant :) I am starting to lean back to sticking with lock and reducing my number of calls, however I am now worried does lock event guarantee I am reading the same value? What if it is cached in one CPU does it invalidate caches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I believe I found the answer and my concern is vindicated!

The code happens to be thread-safe on x86 and AMD64 because they invalidate a CPUs cache when the variable is written to causing subsequent reads to read the variable from memory. to quote Shafqay Ahmed [quoting](http://www.shafqatahmed.com/2008/01/multi-core-cach.html) Jeffrey Richter:

> Since two processors can have different caches, which are copies of the ram, they can have different values. In x86 and x64 processors (according to Jeffrey’s book) are designed to sync the caches of different processors so we may not see the problem.

Incidentally using `lock` and `Interlocked` flushes the variable from cache, so using lock when reading the property would have been safe. From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx:

> Locks guarantee that memory read or modified inside the lock is observed to be consistent, locks guarantee that only one thread accesses a given hunk of memory at a time, and so on.

However there is no guarantee in the CLR specification given when reading a value updated by another thread (without using locking synchronization constructs) will be the most recent. Indeed on ARM I could well get an old value using ThreadSafe class as it is, from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj553518.aspx:

> If your code relies on lock-free algorithms that depend on the implementation of the x86 CLR (rather than the ECMA CLR specification), you’ll want to add the volatile keyword to relevant variables as appropriate. Once you’ve marked shared state as volatile, the CLR will take care of everything for you. If you’re like most developers, you’re ready to run on ARM because you’ve already used locks to protect your shared data, properly marked volatile variables and tested your app on ARM.

So it seems the answer is I can use a `lock` when reading or make my field `volatile`, though perhaps I should use lock and try reduce the number of calls, as a man who worked on the compiler [says](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx):

> The number of situations in which a lock is too slow is very small, and the probability that you are going to get the code wrong because you don't understand the exact memory model is very large. I don't attempt to write any low-lock code except for the most trivial usages of Interlocked operations. I leave the usage of "volatile" to real experts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what you mean by "most up to date value".  You can use locks to ensure that you don't read `Value` at the same time it is being written to, which may yield some oddities, but if you read it then write to it, you won't have the most up to date value.

To handle the oddities I referred to, you can use locks as you have done.  But you seem to desire a different solution.  If you don't want to lock the read, but you want to ensure that the write is atomic such that the read won't return an odd number or some other messy thing when doing a read during a multithreaded write, then I would recommend using the `Interlocked` class.

Simply:

```
Interlocked.Add(ref value, 47);
```

More `Interlocked` functions can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx

These functions are great when working with primitives.  With more complicated objects, other solutions like `ReaderWriterLockSlim` and others will be needed.

Comment: I mean the most up-to-date value at the point in time of the read. Using Interlocked as you have would give the same results - after the Interlocked has performed the Add operation a read, i.e. myThreadSafe.Value could still return the value before the operation! Because value could be sitting in CPU register (as a result of optimisations) only known the thread that called Update() and the other thread calling myThreadSafe.Value would read value from a different location.

Comment: @markmnl So you're concerned about cache coherency.  For x86 CPU's, this is a non-concern - once you write the value, it will invalidate the cache on the current processor and any other processors, forcing them to load the latest written value.  `Interlocked` will work, as will `lock`, or any other .Net thread synchronization construct.

Comment: then it is a concern, I could build library targeting and running on other CPUs

Comment: @markmnl Are you intending to?  If so, that's a critical piece of information you should have added to your question.  Running .Net on a non-x86 CPU is a whole other can of worms.  In such a case, you would need to specify exactly what CPU you're planning on running your code on, and what CLR runtime you'll be utilizing (like Mono).  Each different CPU and runtime will have substantially different ways of handling cache coherency.  If you don't specify this information, then the assumption people will have is that you're targeting x86, which covers probably 99% of use cases for .Net.

Comment: @markmnl As an additional note, `lock` and all the other thread synchronization constructs in .Net may not work in this case for other CPU's as well.  This isn't something isolated to `Interlocked`.